# How to read Python Documentation

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand how I should read python documentation, for example given:
`string.lstrip(s[, chars])` 
How should I read that? I know that brackets means optional, but that 's', what does it mean? Is there a page where it explains how the documentation was written?

Comment: `s` is the function's first parameter. There's nothing significant about the choice of the letter `s`; it's just a name.

Comment: yes, but it can be optional, so why isnt there `[s]`? I can write `"aaa".lstrip()`

Comment: It's not optional; it's mandatory. Note that the method `str.lstrip` is something else. That method only takes a single, optional argument.

Comment: The word "string" here indicates the `string` module, not a string variable. It is literally "string".

Comment: @antox You're looking at the documentation for the string module, not the string type.

Comment: [Here's the documentation for the method you're using.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) It's important to read the right documentation.

Comment: you must not confuse (although they do the same thing) `'foobar '.lstrip()` and `string.lstrip('foobar ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not explictly defined in the documentation, but in

```
string.lstrip(s[, chars])
```

`string` is a Python module, it is not any string (e.g. it can't be `"abc"`).

The parameter `s` is the string (e.g. it can be `"abc"`) that you want to strip. It's mandatory, not optional.

The bracket-enclosed parameter is *optional*, it will be a string and its characters will be stripped from the string.

Some examples of how to call this function are:

```
import string

print string.lstrip("abc", "a") # "bc"
print string.lstrip(" abc") # "abc"
```

**Note:** Don't confuse with `"abc".lstrip()`. They are different functions with identical results. Also, read @user2357112's comment.

**Edit:** On my IDE I've just tested it and it actually shows what is `s` on the docs (pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
def lstrip Found at: string

def lstrip(s, chars=None):
    """lstrip(s [,chars]) -> string

    Return a copy of the string s with leading whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.

    """
    return s.lstrip(chars)

# Strip trailing tabs and spaces
```

Comment: Note that the documentation explicitly says not to use this: "The following list of functions are also defined as methods of string and Unicode objects; see section String Methods for more information on those. You should consider these functions as deprecated, although they will not be removed until Python 3."